# Data not getting inserted into mysql database in asp.net c# web application

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, web-applications, insert

I'm trying to insert simple data in mysql database on a button click but whenever I try to do so, the button click is processed but the data is not getting inserted and also there are no exceptions or errors. I have the database stored in my localhost with exact same table name and column name yet it is creating the problem. Don't know the issue seems to be.

testing.aspx file

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testing.aspx.cs" Inherits="CricketAnalysis2.testing" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

testing.aspx.cs file

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace CricketAnalysis2
{
    public partial class testing : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=cricdb;User Id=root;password=''");
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO drug VALUES ('"+TextBox1.Text+"')";
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're not executing the command. You need to call `ExecuteNonQuery()` method so:

```
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Furthermore, your query is currently open to sql injection, to avoid that you should use paramertised queries and also make use of `using` block to ensure the object is disposed correctly.

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=cricdb;User Id=root;password=''\"";
var query = "INSERT INTO DRUG VALUES(@ParameterName)";
using (var con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
  {
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParameterName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```